# std::string.npos validity

Tags: c++, string, standards

Was `std::string.npos` ever valid? (As opposed to the correct `std::string::npos`.)

I am seeing it a lot in an old project I'm working on, and it does not compile with VS2010.

Is it something from the pre-standard days?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, `std::string.npos` was never valid, and no, it's not something from the pre-standard days.

I see other answers mentioning that MSVC has allowed that notation.

However, MSVC is not a very compliant compiler. For example, it lets you freely bind a temporary to a reference to non-`const`. For another example, for Windows GUI subsystem applications you have to use not well-documented switches to make it accept a standard `main`. Much has improved since Microsoft hired Herb Sutter (and other guy that I don't remember the name of right now) to fix up their monstrous compiler. And in relative terms it has been really great, but in absolute terms, well that compiler is still a bit lacking.

Comment: "For example, it lets you freely bind a temporary to a reference to non-const." This is correct, so long as by "freely" you mean "the compiler issues a warning for using a non-standard extension".

Answer (score 6):

The C with classes syntax for naming a class member was, in fact, a dot:

```
class X {
public:
    void f();
};

void X.f() // a dot! see D&E 2.3
{ 
}
```

However, the `::` syntax had not yet been invented. The `std` namespace didn't exist yet either. Thus the `std::string.npos` wasn't ever valid as either C with classes or standard C++.

I suspect `std::string.npos` is purely Microsoft's extension (or a bug?). It might be inspired by the old syntax, and might be not.

Comment: Wasn't this some thirty years before VS2008?

Comment: @Tomalak: yep, it was. Thus I doubt it has any connection to the 'feature'. You asked about 'pre-standard C++', so I posted the info I know.

Comment: @Tomalak: on a second thought, it's possible. VS2005 accepts static member variables through `.` too. First microsoft's C++ implementation dates back to the early nineties. It's feasible that this feature just remained there untouched till VS2010.

Comment: [According to wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_C%2B%2B): "C 6.0 released in 1989. It added global flow analysis, a source browser, and a new debugger, and included an optional C++ front end." Wow, it's really old... older than me.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Ah, that's interesting then!

Comment: I was hoping for a definitive answer, but this may be as close as we can get.

Comment: @ybungalobill: Unfortunately, I'm reasonably certain in this case the Wiki page is wrong. I'm quite certain C/C++ 7.0 was the first C++ compiler MS ever released (and I started using Microsoft C compilers well before C 6.0 came out). In fact, I can pretty easily remember when Microsoft C changed from being a re-packaged copy of Lattice C to being an actual Microsoft-developed compiler.

Comment: @Jerry: In your opinion, does that have a bearing on the chances of this theory being correct?

Comment: @Tomalak: Come to think of it, probably not. Then again, that it's an MS extension/bug seems more like indisputable fact than theory (the only real question is whether it's intentional). That it might or might not have been inspired by C with Classes syntax doesn't seem much like a theory either.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin I can back that up.  In 1989, I was looking for my first C++ compiler, and the choices were Zortech or Glockenspiel; Borland introduced their C++ the following year, and Microsoft much later.  The Glockenspiel compiler was in fact a port of CFront to the Microsoft C compiler; perhaps this is what the Wiki page is referring to.  (But it's still wrong, since Glockenspiel was a completely independent company, not related to Microsoft in any way.)

Answer (score 3):

Access to any static member via class name and dot was unfortunately allowed by prior versions of MSVC.

```
#include <iostream>
struct A
{
    static int a; 
};
int A::a;
int main()
{
    std::cout << A.a;
}
```

This code is happily accepted by MSVC9.0 with a warning

> Warning   1   warning C4832: token '.' is
>   illegal after UDT 'A'

The C++ standard obviously disallows access to a static member via `className.memberName` (although it *is* perfectly legal to access a static member via an object `object.staticMemberName`).

My common sense tells me that if MSVC is aware that this is not standard and gives a warning, then we can turn that extension off. We go to `Project Propertied -> C/C++ -> Language` and set `Disable Language Extensions` to `Yes`. Do you think anything changes? Of course not, the compiler still accepts the illegal code with the same warning. I sometimes wonder what `Disable Language Extensions` actually does...

Comment: As of VS2005 `/Ze` is deprecated and is the default so officially all it does is change the text displayed on the project properties as the extensions are always on.